# Как записать данные в файл построчно, если файл открыт в режиме "wb"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

```
lines = ["first", "second", "third"]
with open(r"D:\test.txt", "w") as file: # с "wb" это не помогает
    for line in lines:
        file.write(line + '\n')
```

Код приведён для примера, как неподходящий.

Comment: На Windows символ перевода строки `\r\n`. Но лучше просто не пишите текст в режиме `wb`.

Comment: Если вам нужно записывать построчно, то это текстовые данные, а не бинарные. Открывайте тогда в текстовом режиме.

Comment: @КириллМалышев, нет разницы в каком режиме записывать -- все равно туда как байты информация попадет. Поэтому для текстового режима нужно указывать кодировку (по умолчанию она системная), а если для бинарного указать кодировку, то получите ошибку `binary mode doesn't take an encoding argument`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если пишите в бинарном режиме, то записывать нужно байты, а не строку:

```
lines = ["first", "second", "third"]

with open(r"D:\test.txt", "wb") as f:
    for line in lines:
        f.write(bytes(line, 'utf-8') + b'\n')
```

**PS.**

- Аналогом `bytes` будет метод `encode` у строки:

  ```
  f.write(line.encode('utf-8') + b'\n')
  ```